# How to append variables into an existing yaml file?

Tags: ansible

setup.yaml is in /home/user location

```
-
 hosts: localhost
 connection: local

 vars:
   yaml_path: "/home/user/setup.yaml"

 tasks:

   - name: Add missing variables
     set_fact:
       yaml_path: "{{ '/home/user/setup.yaml' | combine(missing_vars_yaml) }}"
     vars:
       missing_vars_yaml:
         ip: " 10.x.x.0  "
         kind: " public  "
```

This is not working, is there any possibility in using copy module ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it with blockinfile module like this:

```yaml
- name: Add missing variables to file
  ansible.builtin.blockinfile:
    path: /home/user/setup.yaml
    block: |
      ip: "10.x.x.0 "
      kind: "public "
```

docu: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/blockinfile_module.html